# Selecting the next select menu after a change event on the first select menu in jQuery/Rails

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to DRY up some jQuery on a page that has multiple dynamic ajax-based selects (Much like on auto websites where you select make, model, etc dynamically). As it stands, my page looks roughly like this:

```
<p>
  <label>...</label>
  <select id="selectA">...</select>
</p>
<p>
  <label>...</label>
  <select id="selectB">...</select>
</p>
```

And my jQuery looks like:

```
$("select#selectA").change(function(){
  // If this works, selectB should turn red.
  $(this).next().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

But selectB never turns red. I've tried various combinations of stuff for the selectors, such as  `"select", "p select", "p select#id",` and `"select#id"` in both the initial and `next()` selector fields. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().next().children('select').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Also if you are adding elements dynamically, you might need to switch to `live`:

```
$("select").live('change',function(){
  // if this works...
  $(this).parent().next().children('select').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Edit: If you can, use css classes for your selects that should be afftected by this. It's much easier (and useful in some situations). Let's say you will add css class `ajaxselect`. You can change this function to:

```
$('.ajaxselect').live('change',function(){
  // if this works...
  $(this).parent().next().children('.ajaxselect').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Edit2: You can see [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ7TK/1/).

Comment: +1. To add, he can use the `startsWith` selector to bind an event handler to all selects with ID starting with 'select': `$("select[id^='select']").change(...`

Comment: Thx, yes that's also a solution :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer and tip, that was my very next step after playing around and getting this to work.